# Form control validation update rules

Tags: angular

i have a custom schema rendering form that i m currently trying to edit

The select component looks like this:

```
<mat-select [formControl]="control" appColor="accent" ngClass="focus-{{propertyName}}" [multiple]="multiple">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.enum[0]">
    {{option.description }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

The component for select extends: AbstractWidgetComponent that looks like this:

```
@Directive()
export class AbstractWidgetComponent extends ControlWidget implements OnInit {

  schema: any;

  control: FormControl;
...
```

The problem is that i dont understand how this form control is generated, where, and how is it able to validate my mat-select.

I need to change the validation rules so that picking an option is not mandatory anymore and i cant seem to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

To validate a `mat-select` you does not need to change anything in it's code. Look here for a custom validator for a `mat-select`: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-with-custom-validator?file=main.ts)

Here a directive will be used:

```
import { Directive, forwardRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALIDATORS, Validator, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[restrictKeywordValidator][ngModel],[restrictKeywordValidator][formControl],[restrictKeywordValidator][formControlName]',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => RestrictKeywordValidatorDirective), multi: true }
    ]
})
// Class definition for Custom Validator
export class RestrictKeywordValidatorDirective implements Validator {
    @Input('restrictKeywordValidator') restrictedKeyword: string;
    validate(ctrl: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {
        return ctrl.value === this.restrictedKeyword ? { 'invalidValue': true } : null;
    }
}
```

Greetings, Florian